# Modifications in Django admin after pen test

Tags: django, django-admin

We have performed a pen test on django admin module using a paid online tool as suggested by our client. It has raised a red flag for a chance of XSS attack in the user groups query. I have tried manually injecting java script in the query. It was accepting script but not executing. But I need to prove technically it was safe from XSS attack. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "user groups query"? Is there a specific page/URL that is being flagged?

Comment: Yes, Specific parameter in a URL has been flagged

Comment: ...what is the URL/parameter?

Comment: It's a basic char field. It's accepting the script

Comment: Are you talking about providing initial values for admin form fields by passing them through the querystring? Django escapes everything by default, view the source and you will find that the script has been escaped (it will look something like `&lt;script&gt;`)

Comment: It's exactly looks like that. which means does Django by default use safe strings?

Comment: Yes, Django escapes all variables/strings by default

Comment: Do you have any technical explanation for that

Comment: The official docs have a section regarding it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/security/#cross-site-scripting-xss-protection

Comment: Thanks mate! Do you have any idea on how to customize the django admin. I'm not asking about adding filters and search. I want to customize input fields for inserting data to models

Comment: Customize how? `formfield_overides` can be used to customize the widget for all fields of a particular type https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides